# Node mongo options parameters vs cursor methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've noticed a few instances within the node MongoDB driver where one can perform a cursor operation either through an `options` parameter or through a chained method, as shown below. Do these perform the same operation or is there some difference (e.g. performance characteristics) between the two?

This example uses `sort` though the same applies in other cases as well (e.g. `limit`). First, as an [options parameter](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find):

```
db.collection.find({}, {sort: {_id: 1}})
```

Now, as a [chained cursor method](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor-sort):

```
db.collection.find({}).sort({_id: 1})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are just two different ways to perform the exact same operation.

In both cases the result is a [`Cursor`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#) with a doc selector of `{}` and a sort parameter of `{_id: 1}`.